# Wago DIN Relay Tool

Tags: relay, din

I’m new to DIN rail components and came across the Wago 788 series relays which seems like it could be a good fit for a project I’m building. The installation flyer mentions an ”operating tool”. The 788-506 relay I got didnt include such a tool. A few questions came to mind:

- Are special tools commonly needed when working on DIN components?
- Why make the connector use a special tool instead of a small phillips set screw?
- Is there any other tool you can use in a pinch to get a wire out of the relay without damaging it?

[image]

Comment: Maybe include the part where it mentions the "special tool" and link to the datasheet? Usually the relays are plain standard socket mounted ones, so they do need to get mechanically secured in some way.

Comment: Also why did you tag this "solid state relay"? This is plain, good old coil-based relay.

Comment: It's basically a screwdriver, and it's not included with the relay holder. https://www.wago.com/us/tools/operating-tool-set-with-partially-insulated-shaft/p/210-722

Comment: "Why make the connector use a special tool instead of a small phillips set screw?" Because screws can loosen over time. They're now against wiring regulations in the UK for inaccessible junctions e.g. under floors and in ceiling voids. And this has nothing to do with it being a DIN component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I have the relay in hand I was able to use my Wera miniature slotted screwdriver which measures 1.8mm wide by 0.3mm thick. You just press into the slot to open the internal wire clamp to remove a wire or insert a stranded wire. Perhaps the Wago "operating tool" is a more perfect size but a small screwdriver like this should do the trick if you're not operating these things all day.

Comment: Josh - Hi, Since you have solved your problem, please [áccept](/help/accepted-answer) your answer, to indicate that you have a solution that works for you. Thanks.